# So what am I missing with this here WPF?

Tags: wpf, winapi

Background: I have a little video playing app with a UI inspired by the venerable Sasami2k, just updated to use VMR9 (i.e. Direct3D9 with DirectShow) and be less unstable.  Currently, it's a C++ app using raw Win32, through necessity: none of the various toolkits are worth a damn.  WPF, in particular, was not possible, due to its airspace restrictions.

OK, so, now that D3DImage exists it might be viable to mix and match D3D/VMR9/DirectShow and WPF. Given past frustrations with Win32's inextensibility, this seems like a good thing.

But y'know, I'm falling at the first hurdle here.

With Win32 I have created (very easily) a borderless window that's resizable, resizes proportionately, snaps to the screen edges, and takes up the whole screen (including taskbar area) when maximized. It's a video app, so these are all pretty desirable properties.

OK, so, how to do the same with WPF?

In Win32, I use:
WM_GETMINMAXINFO to control the maximize behaviour
WM_NCHITTEST to control the resize borders
WM_MOVING to control the snap-to-screen-edges
WM_SIZING to control the resize aspect ratio

However, looking at WPF it seems that the various events arrive too late, unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation?

For example, I don't know when I'm mid-move, as LocationChanged says it fires only once the window has moved (which is too late).
Similarly, it appears that StateChanged only fires once the window has been restored/maximized (when I need the information prior to the maximize, to tell the system the correct maximize size).

And I seem to be completely overlooking where the system tells me about resizes. Likewise the hit testing.

So, uh, am I missing something here, or do I have no choice but to drop back to hooking the wndproc of this thing anyway?  Can I do what I want without hooking the WndProc?

If I have to use the WndProc I might as well stick with my existing codebase; I want to have simpler, cleaner UI code, and moving away from the WndProc is fundamental to this.

If I do have to hook the WndProc, I have to wonder--*why*?  Win32 has got the sizing/sized, moving/moved, poschanging/poschanged window messages, and they're all useful.  Why wouldn't WPF replicate the same set of events?  It seems like an unnecessary gap in functionality.

Plus, it means that WPF is tied to a specific USER32-dependent implementation.  This means that MS can't (in Windows 7 or 8, say) invert the display layer to make WPF "native" and emulate HWNDs and WndProcs for legacy apps--even though this is precisely what MS should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I seem to be completely overlooking where the system tells me about resizes. Likewise the hit testing.

For the resizing you're indeed missing the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) event.
AFAIK there is sadly no OnSizeChanging, OnLocationChanging and OnStateChanging event on a [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window_events.aspx) in .NET

---

> I saw that one, but as far as I can tell it only fires after the size has changed, whereas I need the event to fire during the resize. Unless I'm misreading the docs and it
> actually fires continuously?

It does not fire continuously but you can probably use the [ResizeBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin.aspx) and [ResizeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx) events and be able to do that.

---

> Aren't they WinForms events?

Hmm, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

OK, to answer my own question, I was missing Adorners (never came back in any of the searches I did, so it doesn't seem that they're as widely known as they perhaps should be).

They seem rather more complex than the WndProc overrides, unfortunately, but I think it should be possible to manhandle them into doing what I want.

Comment: Yeah adorners are handy, but their biggest shortcoming imo is lack of XAML support--you have to code everything by hand, which is a nuissance. I'm sure this will be improved in upcoming versions.

Answer (score 1):

In code you can set the WindowStyle property to "None" and WindowsState to "Maximized"

Im not sure what the Xaml would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps override the ArrangeOverride and/or MeasureOverride to make up for those missing resize events? Measure is the first pass, and occurs when a layout needs to adjust for a new size, so it's kind of like a size changing event.